# i18n resourcesToBackend ./app/*/locale/${language}.json

Tags: node.js, import, translate, i18next

I have `i18next` with the option to change languages on the site.

I want to include individual translation files from different directories in my code. I use the `tiny-glob` library for this, which scans for me using a "mask" `./app/*/locale/${language}.json` individual directories in search of translation files.

As a result, I get a list of files in an array. But I'm having trouble appending them using the `import` function. When I include a file using `import` from a variable, I get an error that no such file exists. In contrast, in the case when I paste directly the path to the `inculde` function itself (`import("./../app/register_login/locale/pl.json").then...`) - the file is imported correctly.

How to solve this problem with the import function? Because from what I understand, the `import` with the file is processed already at the compilation stage by webpack.

```
build/
app/
├─ menu/
│  ├─ style.css
│  ├─ locale/
│  │  ├─ en.json
│  │  ├─ pl.json
│  ├─ index.js
├─ register_login/
│  ├─ locale/
│  │  ├─ pl.json
│  │  ├─ en.json
│  ├─ index.js
```

```
App listening on http://localhost:1234
./app/register_login/locale/pl.json
Error: Cannot find module './app/register_login/locale/pl.json'
    at /www/page/build/server/app.js:14:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

```
const glob = require('tiny-glob');
import path from 'path';

import i18n from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-node-fs-backend'
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';

import { sharedConfig } from './i18n.shared';
const config = {};

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(resourcesToBackend((language, namespace, callback) => {
    glob(path.resolve(`./app/*/locale/${language}.json`)).then((lng) => {
      lng.map((el) => {
        //const langLoc = `./../${el}`;
        //const langLoc = "./../app/register_login/locale/pl.json";
        //console.log(langLoc);
        import(`./../${el}`) //import(langLoc)
          .then((resources) => {
            console.log(resources);
            callback(null, resources)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            callback(error, null)
          })
      });
    });
  }))
  .init(Object.assign(sharedConfig, config));

export default i18n;
```